# Javascript MediaRecorder audio recording corrupt

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I am struggeling to get record audio in the browser and make it work properly on mobile as well as desktop.

I am using MediaRecorder to start the recording and I want to send it as a file to my Flask server through a form. However, what I receive is a corrupt file, that sometimes plays on my desktop, but not on my mobile phone. I think it is connected to different mimeTypes that are supported and how the blob gets converted.

Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
function record_audio(){
    if(state == "empty"){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream); 
      mediaRecorder.start();

      state = "recording";
      document.getElementById('stop_btn').style.display = 'block'

      seconds_int = setInterval(
      function () {
        document.getElementById("record_btn").innerHTML = seconds_rec + " s";
        seconds_rec += 1;
    }, 1000);

      
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
        
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
        if(mediaRecorder.state == 'inactive')  makeLink();
      });
  }
}

function makeLink(){
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
      
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      var sound      = document.createElement('audio');
      sound.id       = 'audio-player';
      sound.controls = 'controls';
      sound.src      = audioUrl;
      console.log(audioBlob)
      sound.type     = 'audio/mpeg';
      document.getElementById("audio-player-container").innerHTML = sound.outerHTML;
      
      let file = new File([audioBlob], "audio.mp3",{ type:"audio/mpeg",lastModifiedDate: new Date()});
      let container = new DataTransfer();
      container.items.add(file);
      document.getElementById("uploadedFile").files = container.files;

};
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio that you recorded is most likely not of type `'audio/mpeg'`. No browser supports that out of the box.

If you call `new MediaRecorder(stream)` without the optional second argument the browser will pick the codec it likes best. You can use the `mimeType` property to find out which codec is used by the browser. It can for example be used to construct the `Blob`.

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(
    audioChunks,
    {
        type: mediaRecorder.mimeType
    }
);
```

You would also need to use it in a similar way when creating the `File`. And you probably also need to adapt your backend logic to handle files which aren't MP3s.

Comment: ah great, thanks! However, if I read the mimeType of the MediaRecorder, it's empty, when I don't set it in the options.

Comment: If I recall correctly there is currently a bug in Firefox. It doesn't expose the default `mimeType`. But you can get it when you get the first `dataavailable` event. The `Blob` will have the correct `mimeType`.